# How to add a new less file to semantic ui build system to utilise semantic less variables

Tags: responsive-design, semantic-ui

I want to add a new `.less` file to semantic ui build system. How can i do that?

[This is the file i want to add](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1114#issuecomment-213146552)

like this

```
/* Mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: (@tabletBreakpoint - 1)) {
  [class*="mobile hidden"],
  [class*="tablet only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="computer only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="large screen only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="widescreen only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="or lower hidden"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

i want to utilise semantic variables and compile the new file according to that.

Answer (score 1):

I have added the snippet into default themes `site.overrides` and ran `gulp build`, everything works.